# Store contents of fileReader in a variable

Tags: javascript

trying to do something that I feel like should be releatively straight forward.

I just want to read a text files content and store it in a variable.

Here is my code:

```
readToCSV(file) {
// console.log(file);

    let cat = "";

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (event) {
        if (event.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
            var data = event.target.result;
        }
        console.log("data:", data)
        cat = data;
    };

    reader.readAsText(file)
    console.log("cat:",cat);


};
```

Ive tried just about everything, and keep getting undefined outside the function. Do i just have to nest any further processing inside the onloadend function. That seems silly.

Comment: The FileReader API is asynchronous, which means that loading data into/reading from that variable (ie `cat`) in the way that you're trying is not possible

Comment: "Do i just have to nest any further processing inside the onloadend function. That seems silly" That's the way to do it. That's the nature of JavaScript sadly.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I found a work around and wanted to post it for anyone else who is trying to just get fileContents into a veriable (seriously, why should that be so difficult)

anyways, I ended up wrapping the reader in a promise and storing that.

Anyways, new code as follows:

```
async handleFileUpload(e){
    console.log("e",e)
    await this.setState({file:e[0]})
    console.log("state: ",this.state.file)
       const fileContents = await this.readToText(this.state.file)
       console.log("fc:",fileContents);
    //await this.readToCSV(fileContents)
}

async readToText(file) {

    const temporaryFileReader = new FileReader();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        temporaryFileReader.onerror = () => {
            temporaryFileReader.abort();
            reject(new DOMException("Problem parsing input file."));
        };

        temporaryFileReader.onload = () => {
            resolve(temporaryFileReader.result);
        };
        temporaryFileReader.readAsText(file);
    });

};
```

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to read a text files content and store it in a variable.

The way you're currently doing it, `cat` will be an empty string because of the async nature of the FileReader.

I would do it with a callback.

```
var cat = '';
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0]);
reader.onload = () => storeResults(reader.result);

function storeResults(result) {
  cat = result;
}
```

This way you get the job done and don't have to nest further processing directly within `onloadend`.
Hope that helps!